# Crashes not showing up in fabric.io when reporting from a PacketTunnelProvider

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, fabric.io

I've been trying to set up crashlytics for my application, however the part of my application that I need crash reports for is the `PacketTunnelProvider` which runs separately from the container application.

I've already initialized Crashlytics using

```
override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]? = nil,
                          completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    . . .
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    . . .
}
```

And I'm able to get crashes to report to `fabric.io` using

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

> **Edit:** I've also tried forcing a crash with native C code (`*(int*)0 = 0;`) and that was reported.

However, when my provider crashes with an unplanned crash, **it's not reporting at all.**

I have no idea how to debug this, but I'm positive that my provider is crashing, I just need those crashes to be reporting to `fabric.io`.

Are there specific types of crashes that simply won't report using Crashlytics?

Are there known issues with running Crashlytics from inside of a provider/extension such as the `PacketTunnelProvider`?

Comment: Thanks! Does this run as a dependency of the app or how is it integrated? I'd suggest enabling Fabric debug mode and reproducing the crash to see if it's caught by our system. Is that possible?

Comment: @ToddBurner are you asking if the PacketTunnelProvider runs as a dependency? It runs as an extension on iOS. Which operate similarly to services on most operating systems. How would I go about enabling Fabric debug mode? The crashes are again, unplanned. I can't see what's causing them, so I'm unable to reproduce them since they are sporadic at best. That's why I need these analytics and crash reporting that fabric offers.

Comment: Seems like something odd is happening, but I would love to dig deeper into this with you. Can you turn on debug mode then build and run your app, hit "Stop" in Xcode, then launch the app from the Simulator, cause a test crash, and send me the Console output on relaunch? https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Comment: @ToddBurner I'm unable to run my application from a simulator as the PacketTunnelProvider requires access to the NetworkExtension framework. This framework is only available on physical devices, which I can deploy on and test (assuming that running it in the Simulator is not necessary). That being said, the only crashes I can purposefully force are already reporting. It's the unplanned crashes that aren't reporting for unknown reasons.

**Edit: I've gone ahead and enabled debugging and forced a crash.**